# How to add contents in pivot items in demand

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am struggling with pivot item contents to add contents on demand, but all items are added at once. (load of pivot header)

I am using below MainViewModel.

```
public class ArabicTextTranslationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        ObservableCollection<ArabicTextTranslationHeader> _arabicTextTranslationHeader;
        public ArabicTextTranslationViewModel()
        {
            ArabicTextTranslationHeaders = new ObservableCollection<ArabicTextTranslationHeader>();
            DataSource ds = new DataSource();
            List<Chapter> chapters = ds.getChaptersIndex(); // has 114 pivot headers
            List<ArabicTextWithTranslationContent> content = null;
            foreach (Chapter chapter in chapters)
            {
                content = ds.getArabicTextTranslationContent(chapter);
                ArabicTextTranslationHeaders.Add(new ArabicTextTranslationHeader() { Header = chapter.TName, ArabicTextWithTranslationContent = content }); //loading contents
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ArabicTextTranslationHeader> ArabicTextTranslationHeaders
        {
            get { return _arabicTextTranslationHeader; }
            set
            {
                if (_arabicTextTranslationHeader != value)
                {
                    _arabicTextTranslationHeader = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ArabicTextTranslationHeaders");
                }
            }
        }


        public class ArabicTextTranslationHeader : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }

            string _header;
            public string Header
            {
                get { return _header; }
                set
                {
                    if (_header != value)
                    {
                        _header = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("Header");
                    }
                }
            }

            List<ArabicTextWithTranslationContent> _arabicTextTranslationContent;
            public List<ArabicTextWithTranslationContent> ArabicTextWithTranslationContent
            {
                get { return _arabicTextTranslationContent; }
                set
                {
                    if (_arabicTextTranslationContent != value)
                    {
                        _arabicTextTranslationContent = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("ArabicTextWithTranslationContent");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public class ArabicTextWithTranslationContent : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }

            List<ArabicTextWithTranslation> _arabicTextTranslation;
            public List<ArabicTextWithTranslation> ArabicTextWithTranslation
            {
                get { return _arabicTextTranslation; }
                set
                {
                    if (_arabicTextTranslation != value)
                    {
                        _arabicTextTranslation = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("ArabicTextWithTranslation");
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

and the XAML

```
<phone:Pivot Title="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding ArabicTextTranslationHeaders}"
                    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ArabicTextTranslationDataSource}}">
            <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ArabicTextWithTranslationContent}"
                             FontFamily="./Fonts/ScheherazadeRegOT.ttf#Scheherazade" 
                             FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Foreground="Black" >
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ArabicTextWithTranslation}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                                   Text="{Binding ArabicText.Aya}" FontSize="30" 
                                                   Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:Pivot>
```

The problem is, I am getting exception of out of memory exception and I find out that all contents are loaded at once.

How can I load contents of each pivot item on demand?

Comment: Do you use MVVM light?

Comment: Yeah, but my point is I have 114 pivot items (headers) which is populated and each pivot item contains certain data which I display in listbox. The 1st time every thing is loaded. that is in the constructor of ArabicTextTranslationViewModel(). When I slide to a certain pivot item it throws exception (out of memory).

Comment: 114 pivot items is really not for windows phone. The max is 7 pivot items and 7 is also big. Pivot items is not for that. I think is better for you to create listview.

Comment: Listview? (I dont't think we have this control in wp8). Does it give me the same functionality as pivot give me, because later on I would like to hide the headers and only have the sliding functionality.

Comment: Maybe lazy loading is a solution for you? [Link](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/first-steps-with-caliburn-micro-in-windows-phone-8-lazy-loading-with-pivot/)

Comment: Instead of a pivot, you can use list view with pivot style and when you change selectedItem set the content on your page.

Comment: I am searching listview for wp8, but there is no control called ListView for wp8.

Comment: I think @MatDev8 means you could use a (horizontal) ListBox?

Comment: This new concept, Horizental Listbox. I know of LongLister, but not such Listbox. The functionality which I am looking is in an application called Al Quran in windows phone store. It does this functionality, but I don't know what control s/he uses.

Comment: There are so much app for "Al Quran" name ^^ and yes i mean horizontal listview and use slectedItem for refresh your content. But in all "al Quran" app, listview vertical mode is used.

Comment: Thanks man, Here is the the app link [link](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/al-quran/c93f42cb-c64f-45eb-a628-a24891d82a4c) I could not find listview control in wp8 control collections.

Comment: I just checked the apps you refers, I can't swipe to move to next page. So it looks more like single page, where the content loaded dynamically upon clicking "next surah" menu item. Loading entire Al Quran content at once will takes up lots of space in memory

Comment: For reference, open source WP project : [Quran Phone](http://code.google.com/p/quran-phone/) + [MarketPlace link](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/quran-phone/ca503de6-7cef-4ed3-8060-297578729314). This apps uses different approach though, it is using image instead of arabic texts to keep it as close as possible to experience of reading real Al Quran.